# create an android library with internal use res/raw files

Tags: android

I have an Android library project with text data files in the res/raw directories which are accessed through getAssets().open(R.id.xxx) and InputStream. This content is only accessed and processed in the library.

The purpose of the library is to be a distribution for external customers, and therefore I need to hide the content of the files as well as the implementation of the library. When the library is turned into an app, everything works. But if I use it as a library in an external app, I get a runtime error.

I created an Android app and included the library jar file as an external jar in the libs directory of the application. However, the app gives a run time error of `classdefnotfound R$Raw`. The Library jar file does not have res/raw included in it.

Is there any way to hide the data and implementation inside a library, but also provide the library to the customer?

Answer (score 0):

No. Everything that is not in the `src` folder of your library project will not be included when you deploy the library to a jar. Resources can always be obtained even from a finished apk file; all you have to do is open the apk file as an archive and you will see the entire folder hierarchy for the resources and their files. So, there is no way for you to hide away the resource files from anyone. You will have to find a way to integrate the data you have in your files into your .java files.


What is expected is that you only use .java files in your library, compile into a jar, give the jar to the developer along with your resource files. Then the developer will put those resource files himself in the `res` folder of his own app where your library is being integrated.

Answer (score 0):

With Android Plugin for Gradle version 1.3 or higher you can now declare your resources as private. Initially all the resources in your library are treated as public, when you declare one of the resources as public using the tag `<public>` all the rest of the resources automatically become private.

```
<resources>
    <public name="mylib_app_name" type="string"/>
</resources>
```

Please refer to [Android Studio Public and Private Resources](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/studio-features.html#private-res) for more information.